# How to get the height from the top of the window to the particular div/label in javascript

Tags: javascript, gwt, screen

I want to determine the height from the starting position of the screen to the particular div or the label that i have.

-- label.offsetHeight

-- label.offsetWidth

-- label.offsetTop

is helpful and what this means individually.

Comment: as I want to the find the position of the div at my page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.getBoundingClientRect()`. The strong point of this method is that it returns actual updated values after scroll or resize events:

```
public static native int getDivPosition(String divId)/*-{

  var $label = $doc.getElementById(divId);

  return $label.getBoundingClientRect().top;
}-*/;
```

Comment: where this height is measure from

Answer (score 0):

Try with `GWT JSNI`

```
public static native int getDivPosition(String divId)/*-{

      var label = document.getElementById(divId);

      var labelTop = label.offsetTop;
      var windowHeight = $wnd.innerHeight;
      var scrollPosition = $wnd.pageYOffset;
      var labelScrollHeight = label.scrollHeight;

      return (labelTop - scrollPosition); 

}-*/;
```

For more info have a look at [window size and scrollbar position](http://www.softcomplex.com/docs/get_window_size_and_scrollbar_position.html).

> Please have a look at below links where it is explained visually with examples.

- [HTMLElement.offsetHeight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.offsetHeight)
- [HTMLElement.offsetWidth](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.offsetWidth)
- [HTMLElement.offsetTop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.offsetTop)

Comment: I have tried it all but does not find out that how to calculate the height of the label.Is it actually so that the label.offsetTop will give me the position where the label is in the screen.

Comment: Have you tried to print the values? I want to know what you want if the scroll is in middle then what height you are expecting?

Comment: is the label.offsetTop will calculate its position from the top of the window or from the particular screen.because I think that It is taking from the top of the window as the offsetTop will increase on every label when the scroll it done or the label get increase.as I want to find the top position of label from the particulat page evey time

Comment: If `labelTop=500` and `scrollPosition=300` then what you want?

Comment: I want that the height should be calculated according to the screen that we are viewing ie.on the scrolling the screen page get change ie the next page so the height should calculate from that page

Comment: Sorry I didn't get it. What is concept of page in browser? Where are you getting problem? have you tried to print out those values? install Firefox Firebug plugin and use 'console.log()` to show the values is console.

Comment: page i mean to say that the viewscreen as it change every time when the user scroll

Answer (score 0):

For knowing the height of your widget/element I'd use GQuery.

GQuery.$(yourWidget).height(); should be enough.

For know the distance from the top of your window I use this method:

```
public static int offSet(com.google.gwt.dom.client.Element domElement) {
int top = domElement.getOffsetTop();

for (;;){
  domElement = domElement.getOffsetParent();
  if (domElement == null)
    break;
  top = top + domElement.getOffsetTop();
}

return top;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

In GWT it's very simple:

```
int pos = label.getAbsoluteTop();
```

If you want it in Javascript, use:

```
var elementTop = function(element) {
    var top = 0;
    do {
        top += element.offsetTop  || 0;
        element = element.offsetParent;
    } while(element);

    return top;
};
```

Comment: Why do you need it in JSNI if you use GWT? Anyway, you can always pass it to your JSNI code. See my update for JavaScript code.